# Executing linux command from java using exec('command') method

Tags: java, linux, filenames

I am trying to execute a Linux command from my java class using the method exec() from the Runtime class in this way:

```
public static String xxUtilInfoFile  (String sPath , String sFileName) throws Exception
{            
    Runtime r = null;
    Process p = null;   
    String line_value="";
    String output_data="";

    /*execute the process*/
    r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    p = r.exec("file -bi " + sPath + sFileName);
    p.waitFor();

    /*Return the standard error output*/
    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    output_data = in.readLine();

    return output_data;        
}
```

The Linux command I want to use is `file -bi fileName` and it runs well except in the case the fileName has blanks inside, and that is the point.

I've already tried to use double quotes and backslash (`\`) because this method runs in the Linux bash console, but it doesn't run if I pass it as an argument of exec method.

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should pass an array of Strings to the exec() method at line 9 of your code:

```
p = r.exec(new String[]{ "file", "-bi", sPath, sFileName});
```

Comment: Thanks. It runs, but with a little change.

Comment: The solution is: 'p = r.exec(new String[]{ "file", "-bi", sPath + sFileName});'